# get application path codeigniter with out contents after last slash

Tags: codeigniter, php

hi i am using codeigniter in my application .

for my application i need application path only before the last slash

like this

if application path is

```
http://localhost/elephanti/connections/fb_connection/invite_friends
```

i want to get

```
http://localhost/elephanti/connections/fb_connection
```

it is for a plae like this

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '"+APPPATH+"'testapp';</script>";
```

i tried to use `'"+APPPATH+"'../testapp'` but could not , please help ...................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the last part will always be the 4th, you can use a "dirty way" like this:

```
$url = site_url($this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/'.$this->uri->segment(3));
```

And then:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '".$url."'/testapp';</script>";
// here, though, I don't understan how "testapp" goes into the url..as a segment?
```

This will create a valid CI url using only the first 3 segments.

Alternatively, you can use the `uri_string()` function, wich returns only the segment part of the url. On this, you can explode/str_replace/array_pop/do whatever you need to and pass the new elaborated string on the `site_url()` function wichi will build the correct URL for you.

I don't understand what "testapp" is there or, do you want to substitute the last segment of your url with that? So that you have, in your example, `http://localhost/elephanti/connections/fb_connection/testapp` ?

Keep in mind that both uri_string() and site_url() are functions from the [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) so you need to load it.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Codeigniter APPPATH referes to the location on the disk and not the url of the application. What you are looking for is base_url(). base_url() return the base location of your site, which usually is the domain.
2. Concatenation in php is done with the dot operator: "."

   echo "top.location.href = '".base_url()."'testapp';";